# What is the mean and variance of an MA(4) process with time drift?

Tags: time-series, variance, mean, trend, moving-average

For a project I need to simulate a relatively smooth time series with an upward drift.

This is what I came up with:

$$y_t = \mu + \alpha t+ \sum_{j=0}^{q=4} \theta_{j} e_{t-j}$$ where
$\theta_j = 0.2^{j}$, $\mu = 1$, $\alpha=0.01$ and I seeded the errors to be $e_t \sim N(0, 1)$

How would one estimate the mean and variance for this? I believe it is weakly stationary but not sure how to estimate it at a particular time point.

Here is a graph of one realization with T=100:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Moving-average models are always weakly stationary because they are finite linear combinations of a white noise sequence for which the first two moments are time invariant. For example, consider the $MA(1)$ model
$$r_{t}=c_{0}+a_{t}-\theta_{1}a_{t-1} \quad \text{or} \quad r_{t}=c_{0}+(1-\theta_{1}B)a_{t}$$

Taking expectation of the model, we have $$\mathbb{E}(r_{t})=c_{0}$$
which is time invariant of MA(1). Taking the variance we have :

$$Var(r_{t})=\sigma_{a}^2+\theta_{1}^2\sigma_{a}^2 = (1+\theta_{1}^2)\sigma_{a}^2.$$

where we use the fact that $a_t$ and $a_{t−1}$ are uncorrelated. Again, $Var(r_t)$ is time invariant. Your question and the previous statement applies to general $MA(q)$ models, and we obtain two general properties. First, the constant term of an $MA$ model is the mean of the series [i.e., $\mathbb{E}(r_{t})=c_{0}$]. And second in general, the variance of an $MA(q)$ model is:

$$Var(r_{t})=(1+\theta_{1}^2+\theta_{2}^2 \dots +\theta_{q}^2)\sigma_{a}^2.$$

**Edit**

This $ΜΑ(4)$ model is from Hamilton's book "Time Series Analysis" page 50.I have added the $a$ term in the example.Hope that answers your question.

```py
# MA(4) :Y_t= e_t - 0.6e_t-1,_ 1 + 0.3e_t- 2 - 0.5e_t-3 + 0.5e_t-4
n_samples = 100
θ1 = -0.6
θ2 = 0.3
θ3 = -0.5
θ4 = 0.5
μ = 5
α = 0.01
y = ε = np.random.normal(0,1,size=n_samples)
for t in range(n_samples):
    y[t] = μ +α*t +ε[t] + θ1*ε[t-1] + θ2*ε[t-2] + θ3*ε[t-3] + θ4*ε[t-4]
from statsmodels.graphics import tsaplots
fig = tsaplots.plot_acf(y, lags=12)
```

Comment: But isn't my model different because I have a time trend alpha*t. I see how the errors drop away but does this answer generalize to something with a time trend?

Comment: In your variance expression, a plus seems to turn into a minus. @asd, you have a valid point; it does not generalize straightforwardly. Your model does not have unconditional mean or variance, as they would depend on time.

Comment: @RichardHardy yes I edited.thanks

Comment: @asd I have added some code in my answer